# Element no longer draggable after adding parameter to d3 drag behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

The following code creates a circle and makes it draggable:

**HTML:**

```
<svg width='400' height='400'>
  <rect width='100%' height='100%'></rect>
  <circle transform='translate(259.5,197)' r='10'></circle>
</svg>
```

**JS:**

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragMove)
 d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('transform', 'translate(' + '100px' + ',' + '100px' + ')').attr('r', '5').call(drag)

 function dragMove(test) {
   var x = d3.event.x
   var y = d3.event.y
   console.log(test)
   d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + '200px' + ',' + '200px' + ')')
 }
```

It works. But when I add an argument to `dragMove`:

```
'drag', function() { dragMove('test') }
```

The dragging functionality stops working (`console.log(test)` outputs `'test'`, though)

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/d8doyc9r/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be this way:

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function(d) {

   dragMove(this);//pass the this
 })


 function dragMove(me) {


   var x = d3.event.x
   var y = d3.event.y
   //operate on me
   d3.select(me).attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
 }
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/yx0b1z6a/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it worked! One question, why is the `d` in `function(d)` necessary? I removed it and nothing happened.

Comment: I always see that `d` in d3 sample code. I think someone made the mistake and then people included it because of convention, ha.